# Source that Tisha B'av is the day of mourning for all tragedies, even if they did not fall out then?

Tags: sources-mekorot, history, mourning-aveilus, tisha-bav

I have heard (in the context of when Jews should mourn for those lost in the Holocaust), that Tish'a B'av is the day on which we mourn all tragedies, even those that did not occur on that day.  What is the earliest source for this idea?

Comment: Isn't there a Midrash that says something to the point that G-d said regarding the spy incident, "You have cried for no reason. I will make this night a night of sadness for generations. And that night was *Tish'a B'Av*?" Wouldn't that Midrash have set a precedent already for crying for all sorts of tragedies even those that did not occur on Tish'a B'av?

Comment: @DanF Maybe that just means that lots of tragedies will occur on Tisha B'av.

Comment: @Alex That certainly would be the most logical and "obvious" meaning. But, note that the Midrash phrasing is general. It calls it a day of **crying** not a day of tragedies. One of my family members compiled a yahrtzeit list of family members. The yahrtzeit of 5 of my uncles / aunts who died during the Holocaust are on Tisha B'Av, b/c no one knew exactly when they died or where they are buried. Yes, it's a horrible personal thought, that undoubtedly many families share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi) (or pesudo-Rashi) to II Chronicles 35:25 writes:

> כשמזדמן להם שום צער ובכיה שהם מקוננים ובוכים על המאורע הם מזכירים זה
>   הצער עמו דוגמא בתשעה באב שמזכירים קינות על ההרוגים בגזירות שאירעו
>   בימינו כן יבכיון על מות יאשיהו דוגמא ותהי חק בישראל וגומר לתנות לבת
>   יפתח הגלעדי ארבעה ימים בשנה

Rashi here compares the death of Yoshiyahu to Tisha B'av, and notes that on Tisha B'av we lament those who were killed in our times.

While this does not explicitly say that all tragedies should be mourned on (and only on) Tisha B'av, it certainly implies something of some extent, and is quoted by later authorities as the source for why we do not create new days of mourning.

See, for example, the following statement of [R. Joseph Ber Soloveitchik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_B._Soloveitchik) recorded in *The Rav Thinking Aloud* p.244-245

> Rashi in *Shmuel Bais* says all *yimay aveilus*, pertaining to all
>   disastrous events which took place in our history, all expressions of
>   *aveilus* should take place on *Tisha b'Av*, not a separate *Yom Ha'Shoah*. Rashi says it.
>
> Not in *Shmuel Bais*, excuse me, it's in *Divrei HaYamim*.

Another similar source from around the same time comes from one of the Kinnot about the First Crusade, written by R. Kalonymus Ben Yehuda:

> וְכִי אֵין לְהוֹסִיף מוֹעֵד שֶׁבֶר וְתַבְעֵרָה  וְאֵין לְהַקְדִּים
>   זוּלָתִי לְאַחֲרָהּ  תַּחַת כֵּן הַיּוֹם לִוְיָתִי אֲעוֹרְרָה 
>   וְאֶסְפְּדָה וְאֵילִילָה וְאֶבְכֶּה בְּנֶפֶשׁ מָרָה

Here the author states that we cannot create a new day of mourning, so we therefore mourn the Crusade on Tisha B'av.

Like the previous source this does not quite explicitly state that all tragedies should be mourned on (and only on) Tisha B'av. This source is also quoted by later authorities as a source that we cannot add new days of mourning.

For example, [R. Moshe Feinstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Feinstein) in [Igrot Moshe Y.D. 4:5:11](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=922&pgnum=333) writes that this is why we don't enact a special day of mourning for the Holocaust and other modern tragedies:

> ובדבר הגזירות שבעוה"ר נהרגו ערך עשרה פעמים ששים ריבוא ע"י הרשעים היטלער וחבריו ימ"ש שמהראוי הרי היה צורך איזה יום קבוע לתענית ולתפילה שתמה מע"כ על שעדיין לא נעשה כלוםהנה בקינות שכל ישראל אומרים בתשעה באב מפורש שמה שלא תיקנו יום מיוחד
>   לתענית ולבכיה על גזירות מסעות הצלב שהיו הגזירות בכל מדינות יוראפ שגרו
>   שם רוב היהודים ונחרבו כמה עיירות וכרכים ונקרא על שם שנת תתנ"ו וגם בא"י
>   הרגו שם הרבה יהודים משום דאין לקבוע עוד יום לתענית ולבכי שלכן צריך
>   להזכירם בקינות דאומרים בתשעה באב על חורבן המקדש ומאותו טעם עצמו אין
>   לקבוע יום אחד מיוחד גם לגזירות שהיו בזמננו והוא בכלל כל הגזירות שהיו
>   במשך כל הגלות הארוך הזה